# Unable to collapse navigation bar from example in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make my navigation bar collapsable, but the style I used from [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/narrow-jumbotron/) doesn't seem to be compatible with `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">`, which instead causes the bar to disappear. The issue is that every bit of code I've seen uses that particular line, so it's not like there's a common alternative. Trying to use the div classes from working examples usually messes up the styling.

I've trimmed down the code as much as possible to keep to the styling as it is, alternatively here is a link to it: https://www.bootply.com/lLZDFmgE8t

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
      padding-top: 1.5rem;
      padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    }
    .header {
      padding-bottom: 1rem;
      border-bottom: .05rem solid #e5e5e5;
    }
    .header h3 {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      line-height: 3rem;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills float-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><h3 class="text-muted">My Website</h3></a>
      </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone might be able to figure why the usual code is incompatible, and if there's any potential fix for it. I love how well the collapse works on mobile devices, but I also like the style of that particular navigation bar.

Comment: You don't have the bootstrap linked before the closing </body> tag. Go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/ and look where it says Add our optional JavaScript plugins, jQuery, and Popper.js) near the end of your pages, you don't put that in the head section

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it just recommends that to avoid longer loading times (forgot why I moved it up though)